# How to pass XML file to layout custom attribute?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

While developing a library module I decided to extern all UI attributes in a metadata file using XML - which will be latter validated againts a XSD schema. Currently I have both, XML and XSD, on assets folder of my project. I want to pass the XML reference in a custom attribute for my Custom View - doing something like `app:cestyle="@assets/my_xml_file"`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets are not mapped in `R` file so you can't access them like @string or @dimen, etc.

I would suggest either using a `string` resource that equals asset file name or `res/raw` folder to hold your xml files.

Comment: But is it possible to access any of these value from layout XML? Either from raw or XML res folder?

Comment: Of course, create an attribute of `reference` format like  `<attr name="cestyle" format="reference"/>`. Then in xml use either @xml/my_xml_file or @raw/my_xml_file.